# python - build adjacency list from list of nodes and edges

Tags: python, dijkstra, adjacency-list

I have a list of node and edge objects from the National Highway Planning Network database. A lot of the data is hidden from me but this is what is given to me:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, longitude, latitude, state, description):
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.state = state
        self.description = description

class Link: 
    """A bi-directional edge linking two NHPN nodes."""

    def __init__ (self, begin, end, description):
        """create a link given its beginning and end (which must be nodes)
        and possibly a description string."""
        self.begin = begin
        self.end = end
        self.description = description
```

I know there isn't a lot of information given but I am trying to build an adjacency list from this data. I would very much like to use a dictionary. This is what I tried:

```
for node in nodes:
    adj[node] = None
for edge in edges:
    adj[node] = (edge.begin, edge.end) #edge.begin and edge.end being node's neighbors
```

followed by a print statement, just to see if it worked. But it never printed, which worries that the input is enormous and my code will be incredibly slow. How can I revise my implementation? I would very much like to use a dictionary but I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: Do you have to use those class definitions? Dictionaries require hashable keys, and neither of those classes are hashable.

Comment: @Robᵩ if you mean the Node and Link, yes most likely because I can't imagine there's any other way to iterate through the nodes and edges. If you mean the longitude/latitude/etc and begin/end, probably not but I can't think of a way to do it without the begin/end

Comment: The NHPN database appears to be quite large. I think the question from @Robᵩ is aimed at discovering what if any changes can be made to the data storage format. Do you already have all these records in memory? Are you using someone else's parser for the XML file? Also, what's the intended use case for the adjacency list? Insertion into a database? Building a map? Solving the traveling salesman problem?

Comment: @AustinHastings dijskstra's algorithm to find shortest path from some area around me to some area far away from me (san diego, for example)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a program that computes the adjacency list for a very small set of highways. I have used the code from your question as much as I could.

```
from pprint import pprint
class Node:
    def __init__(self, longitude, latitude, state, description):
        self._longitude = longitude
        self._latitude = latitude
        self.state = state
        self.description = description

    @property
    def longitude(self):
        return self._longitude
    @property
    def latitude(self):
        return self._latitude

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.longitude, self.latitude))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Node({_longitude!r}, {_latitude!r}, {state!r}, {description!r})'.format(**vars(self))

class Link:
    """A bi-directional edge linking two NHPN nodes."""

    def __init__ (self, begin, end, description):
        """create a link given its beginning and end (which must be nodes)
        and possibly a description string."""
        self.begin = begin
        self.end = end
        self.description = description

chicago = Node(-87, 41, 'IL', 'Windy City')
bloomington = Node(-89, 40, 'IL', 'Twin City')
indy = Node(-86, 40, 'IN', 'Naptown')
nodes = [ chicago, bloomington, indy ]
edges = [
    Link(chicago, bloomington, 'I-55'),
    Link(chicago, indy, 'I-65'),
    Link(indy, bloomington, 'I-74'),
]

adj = {}
for edge in edges:
    adj.setdefault(edge.begin, set()).add(edge.end)
    adj.setdefault(edge.end, set()).add(edge.begin)
pprint(adj)
```

Here is what it would look like if we didn't have to use `Link` and `Node` as provided:

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import namedtuple

Node = namedtuple('Node', 'longitude latitude state description')
Link = namedtuple('Link', 'begin end description')

chicago = Node(-87, 41, 'IL', 'Windy City')
bloomington = Node(-89, 40, 'IL', 'Twin City')
indy = Node(-86, 40, 'IN', 'Naptown')
nodes = [ chicago, bloomington, indy ]
edges = [
    Link(chicago, bloomington, 'I-55'),
    Link(chicago, indy, 'I-65'),
    Link(indy, bloomington, 'I-74'),
]

adj = {}
for edge in edges:
    adj.setdefault(edge.begin, set()).add(edge.end)
    adj.setdefault(edge.end, set()).add(edge.begin)
pprint(adj)
```

And here is one without using any class definitions at all:

```
from pprint import pprint

chicago = (-87, 41, 'IL', 'Windy City')
bloomington = (-89, 40, 'IL', 'Twin City')
indy = (-86, 40, 'IN', 'Naptown')
nodes = [ chicago, bloomington, indy ]
edges = [ 
    (chicago, bloomington, 'I-55'),
    (chicago, indy, 'I-65'),
    (indy, bloomington, 'I-74'),
]

adj = {}
for edge in edges:
    adj.setdefault(edge[0], set()).add(edge[1])
    adj.setdefault(edge[1], set()).add(edge[0])
pprint(adj)
```